# R is not reading my csv file properly?

Tags: r, csv

I am new to R Programming language. I can able to load this csv file into R. it was semicolon separated csv file. There are totally 33 attributes. but R reads it as 1 column, The link for dataset is

https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Student+Performance#

I had tried using sep(";") while reading csv file in R. i had also tried to convert various formats from csv to text,dif, and nothing works.

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: have you tried read.csv() or read.csv2() ?

Comment: https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/00320/ . This  is the direct link to download.  The question may be silly. But please help me

Comment: friend. i had tried both. nothing works

Comment: `student <- read.table("student-por.csv", header=TRUE, sep=";", quote="\"", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)`

Comment: if this does not work, you should check whether you're in the right directory

Comment: Thank you very much friend. Its working find. Hats off to you.

Comment: Maybe it would be helpful to use `getwd()` to see if `R ` is reading from the directory where your file is. If necessary, the directory can be changed with `setwd()`.

Comment: I can understand you don't upvote this answer, but it is a new user struggling who has put effort into the question, and is having a hard time. Why downvote?

Answer (score 2):

```
df1 <- read.csv('student-mat.csv', sep=";")
df2 <- read.csv('student-por.csv', sep=";")
```

Works without any problem. Maybe you had just forgotten to put the equal sign between `sep` and `";"`.

```
> str(df1)
'data.frame':   395 obs. of  33 variables:
$ school    : Factor w/ 2 levels "GP","MS": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
$ sex       : Factor w/ 2 levels "F","M": 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 1 2 2 ...
$ age       : int  18 17 15 15 16 16 16 17 15 15 ...
$ address   : Factor w/ 2 levels "R","U": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
$ famsize   : Factor w/ 2 levels "GT3","LE3": 1 1 2 1 1 2 2 1 2 1 .
....
```

Answer (score 0):

Using your data, it works well for me:

```
student_por <- read.csv2("student-por.csv")
student_mat <- read.csv2("student-mat.csv")
```